# Nerdfonts, what's the difference between different nerd fonts?

Tags: fonts

In other words, is the difference only in appearance or the type of characters/icons they contain as well? I assume both. If there is a difference in appearance but also in characters/icons, how can we compare them? When we go to their [download page](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads), we can compare them by appearance, but I couldn't find a comparison by characters/icons. The short "**Info:**" below every download is not very informative. Also, what is a patched font, or to patch a font?

Comment: This is something you should be asking Nerdfonts

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**. This *may* be a better fit at [webapps.se]. Be sure to read their [FAQ](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help) before posting to make sure your question meets their requirements.